# Locally declared object's internal memory intact outside scope?

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

The function `f1` creates an instance of `foo` and sets `foo.ptr[0] = 2`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
        int *ptr;
        inline foo(int a) {
                ptr = new int[a];
        }
        inline ~foo() {
                delete[] ptr;
        }
};
foo f1() {
        foo a(5);
        a.ptr[0] = 2;
        return a;
}
int main() {
        foo a = f1();
        cout<<a.ptr[0]<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

What I expected as the output: **junk value**.

`f1` returns **by value**, which means a copy of `a` is made and this copy even shares the same memory locations at which their (`a` and it's copy) respective `ptr`s point at.

Outside `f1`, `a` gets destroyed.
It's destructor is called which will deallocate `ptr`'s memory. This means the memory location which the copy's `ptr` points at is also invalid. So, I expect a junk value as output.

The output actually is `2`.

Why?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. You're calling `delete[]` on an already freed memory location.

Comment: Your expectations are tantamount to relying on a defined outcome, and there is no such beast with undefined behavior. For some insight on what all these references to undefined behavior really mean, [see this q&a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: @chris, Already freed memory location? I thought whenever an object goes out of scope, it's destructor gets called. Now, the destructor here uses `delete` to free the memory allocated to `ptr`. Right?

Comment: @learner, Yes, the object in the function is destroyed and the memory freed. Then, there's a theoretical copy to `a` in `main`, so the returned one might get destroyed as well, and then the one in `main` is destroyed. They all share the same pointer, and there's only one `new[]`.

Comment: @chris, Ah, you meant `You're calling delete[] on an already freed memory location` **when the program terminates** (the object declared in `main` function goes out of scope), right?

Comment: @learner, Yes, that's what I meant, along with the possibility of when `main`'s `a` is constructed if the compiler so chooses.

Comment: @chris, sorry for being persistent. But how will that possibly happen during construction? Construction here means using the implicit copy constructor, which will simply copy every member. Will `delete` get used at all at the point of construction?

Comment: @learner, The function returns a temporary value, the main one is copy-constructed from it, and the temporary is destroyed. A compiler could choose to elide that copy, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard never says that you should expect a "junk value". Instead, it says you'll get undefined behaviour. Since you are not following the rule of three (or five), the dynamically allocated array of `int`s is destroyed when `f1` returns and the object `a` ends up with a pointer to the destroyed array. To access this gives you undefined behaviour.

The reason you're likely seeing the value `2` is because that memory location hasn't been reused since the value 2 was in there. However, reasoning about this is meaningless as far as the standard is concerned.